# REST сервис в JSF приложении

Tags: jsf, rest

Всем привет. 
Как правильно реализовать rest сервис в jsf приложении и возможно ли вообще создание rest сервиса в jsf приложении? 

Попробовал сделать так:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class TestRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

Приложение запускается без ошибок, но сервис не находится по адресу
по `http://localhost:8080/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/test/testMsg`.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Приведённый вами код никак не относится к JSF. Это JAX-RS и этот стандарт предназначен именно для разработки REST-сервисов.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо, а в JSF приложении вообще как-нибудь возможно реализовать REST-сервис или это бессмысленная затея?